# Find Last item with queryDSL and spring-data-jpa implementation with LockMode

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I want to find the last inserted item from table "product" with Spring-Data-JPA (Hibernate implementation) and QueryDSL(type safe) to generate SQL: SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

I have call findLast() from Service with @Transactional and want to setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) and to add "SELECT .. FOR UPDATE" in this SQL query.

```
public class ProductRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements ProductRepositoryCustom {

    public ProductRepositoryImpl() {
        super(Product.class);
    }

    //SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
    @Override
    public Product findLast() {
        QProduct product = QProduct.product;
        return from(product).orderBy(product.id.desc()).limit(1L).fetchOne();
    }
}
```

This is the generated SQL

Hibernate: select * from ( select product0_.id as id11, product0_.description as description21, product0_.price as price31, product0_.productStatus as productStatus41, product0_.quantity as quantity51 from PRODUCTS product0 order by product0.id desc ) where rownum <= ?

The question: What is the best way to add setLockMode() in repository extending org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslRepositorySupport?

I have try this but it return Object and needs to cast (Product):

```
getQuerydsl().createQuery(product)
.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).orderBy(product.id.desc()).limit(1L).fetchOne();
```

Comment: From the generated SQL, it does not appear that the limit is ignored, its just that it uses your database's internal _rownum_ semantic to return all rows where `rownum <= 1`

Comment: yes but is executed in subquery and this cannot work with locking selected rows  with "SELECT .. FOR UPDATE" and I have check that if I skip limit() the generated SQL is the same rownum <= 1 is coming from fetchOne()

Comment: What if you specify the `limit()` and tell it to call `fetch()` or `fetchResults()`.  Does the generated SQL work as you would expect?

Comment: My bad, it`s Oracle DB and limit works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this part of code , I think it' s will works like that :

```
  QProduct product = QProduct.product;
 return (Product)getQuerydsl().createQuery(product)
.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).orderBy(product.id.desc())
.limit(1L).fetchOne();
```

Hibernate will generate the following queries: 
Hibernate: select * from ( select product0_.id as id1_1_, ...... from PRODUCTS product0_ order by product0_.id desc ) where rownum <= ?

Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_1_, .... from PRODUCTS product0_ where product0_.id=? for update

Attention:   There are two SQL queries and the row can be locked only by ID.
The problem is structural it' s better to separate query instead of let the Hibernate do that.

Comment: Yes you are right. The better solution is to not try locking with one custom SQL query and first to select last row without locking. This can be easy done using spring-data CrudRepository query by method name like: findTop1ByOrderByIdDesc() and next to have @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) Product findById(Long id);